# Calculate the distance between multi geolocations points

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, polyline, google-polyline, google-distancematrix-api

My application collects geolocation point from the user every certain amount of time, I am trying to use these points in order to calculate the distance from the first point through all of the points.

please note that when the user moves in a straight line, the geolocation points do not form a straight line, because the points I collect have a margin of error due to inaccuracy, thus I can't use something like [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) because it will give incorrect value (longer distance than real distance)

and I can't use [Google Maps Distance API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro) because it calculates the distance between 2 points only, and it will be so expensive to call it 200 times to calculate distance through all points.

and I want to calculate this value on the server-side because of some security rules I have. so using the google maps SDK in the front end to calculate it is not an option either.

Any idea ...

Comment: One option would be to simplify the line, then run the data through the Google Roads API (assuming the travel is on roads), then measure the length of the resulting line (following the roads).

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it worked! I converted my raw geolocation points to points on the real road then I used an offline method to calculate the distance using the snaped points

Comment: Can you provide any code example you had trouble with and post a solution so your question can be of any help in the future? At the moment is completly unclear what you did to reach and solve the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone facing the same problem,I have followed this link
https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap

here is my code in PHP

```
// snap the collected points from user to the nearest road using google API
$fields = array(
    'path' => '60.170880,24.942795|60.170879,24.942796|60.170877,24.942796|60.170902,24.942654',
    'key' =>  '<YOUR_KEY_HERE>'
);
$url = "https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?" . http_build_query($fields, '', '&');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response  = curl_exec($ch);
$response = json_decode($response);

$totalDistance = 0;
$previousPoint = null;
foreach ($response->snappedPoints as $pointOnRoad) {
    if(!$previousPoint){
        $previousPoint = $pointOnRoad;
        continue;
    }

    $totalDistance += getDistance($pointOnRoad->location->latitude, $pointOnRoad->location->longitude,
                                  $previousPoint->location->latitude, $previousPoint->location->longitude);
}

echo $totalDistance;


// calculate distance between 2 geo points
function getDistance($latitude1, $longitude1, $latitude2, $longitude2) {

    $earth_radius = 6371;

    $dLat = deg2rad($latitude2 - $latitude1);
    $dLon = deg2rad($longitude2 - $longitude1);

    $a = sin($dLat/2) * sin($dLat/2) + cos(deg2rad($latitude1)) * cos(deg2rad($latitude2)) * sin($dLon/2) * sin($dLon/2);
    $c = 2 * asin(sqrt($a));
    $d = $earth_radius * $c;

    return $d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to simplify the line, then run the data through the [Google Roads API](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/roads/intro) (assuming the travel is on roads), then measure the length of the resulting line (following the roads).

Answer (score 0):

We are having similar kind of requirement. There are 2 paths and we need to make sure that each node in 1st path (except start and end) are at least 100 KM away from each other of 2nd path.

Can you please share code snippet or logic behind this.

[image: Problem Statement]

Using Haversine formula in loop will impact performance. So, please suggest some better solution.